# How do I show the value correctly in my form?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, forms

I'm trying to generate a from from the data I have in my state :

```
const { id } = this.props.match.params;
const formGen = this.state.arr.map(arr => {
  if (id == arr.id) {
    const inner = this.state.arr.input.map(inputs => (
      <div>
        <h1>{arr.name}</h1>
        <label>{inputs.inputLabel}</label>
        <input value={inputs.inputValue} type={inputs.inputType} />
      </div>
    ));
  }
});
```

Now, I have no idea how to make it show up in the render tab because I have a variable inside a variable :

```
<form />
        {formGen.inner}
      </div>
```

this is my state I'm trying to map

```
 arr: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'firstForm',
        input: [
          {
            inputLabel: 'wowLabel',
            inputType: 'wowType',
            inputValue: 'wowValue'
          },
          {
            inputLabel: 'wowLabel2',
            inputType: 'wowType2',
            inputValue: 'wowValue2'
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: why don't you put {formGen.inner} inside of a form?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the response in variable, you could return it, else return undefined and then filter out the response.

```
const { id } = this.props.match.params;
const formGen = this.state.arr.map(arr => {
  if (id == arr.id) {
    return this.state.arr.input.map(inputs => (
      <div>
        <h1>{arr.name}</h1>
        <label>{inputs.inputLabel}</label>
        <input value={inputs.inputValue} type={inputs.inputType} />
      </div>
    ));
  }
  return;
}).filter(Boolean);
```

After this, you could render it like

```
 <form />
    {formGen}
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for help! but it seems I have another problem, I added the state I'm mapping in my comment, because when i use this code it says "return this.state.arr.input.map is undefined" do you happen to know why?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { id } = this.props.match.params;

// replace the first map with a find
const arr = this.state.arr.find(a => a.id == id);

// if arr is defined
if(arr){
    const inner = arr.input.map(inputs => (
      <div>
        <h1>{arr.name}</h1>
        <label>{inputs.inputLabel}</label>
        <input value={inputs.inputValue} type={inputs.inputType} />
      </div>
    ));

} else {
  // indicate to the user the that id was not found and what to do to fix the problem
}
```

```html
<form>{inner}</form>
```

Comment: I just have one question, why did you use == instead of ===, I noticed when I use === it doesn't work, even tho its the same number, do you happen to know why?

Comment: I think the id from the params is a string and your state id is a number.